# ASP.NET async/await part 2

Tags: asp.net, async-await

I have a variation of the benefits-of-async/await-on-ASP.NET from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867005/does-async-and-await-increase-performance-of-an-asp-net-application).

My understanding is that asynchrony is not the same thing as parallelism. So, on a web server, I wonder about how much benefit async/await brings to ASP.NET pages.

Isn't IIS+ASP.NET already really good at allocating threads for requests, and if onen page is busy waiting for a resource the server will just switch to processing another request that has work to do?

There are a limited number of threads in the pool for ASP.NET to use - does async use them any more effectively?

As Mr. Skeet pointed out in answering the question above, we're not talking about blocking a UI thread. We're already multi-threaded and the web response can't be completed until all the request's tasks are done, async or not, right?

I guess what it boils down to is this:

Is there any benefit to an async read of a resource (say a file or DB request) in an ASP.NET page vs. blocking on it?

Comment: Did you actually read the Jon Skeet's answer you mentioned? He does explain the benefits of using `async` in ASP.NET.

Comment: @svick: Thank you for reading. Yes, I read Jon's answer but in so many cases he's saying "it depends," which I guess is the ONLY answer he *can* give. I would like to understand the threading implications of async/await on a high-volume web server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> if one page is busy waiting for a resource the server will just switch to processing another request that has work to do?

I don't think so. I would be *very* surprised if this were the case. It's theoretically possible, but very complex.

> There are a limited number of threads in the pool for ASP.NET to use - does async use them any more effectively?

Yes, because when you `await` something, the thread for that request is immediately returned to the pool.

> We're already multi-threaded and the web response can't be completed until all the request's tasks are done, async or not, right?

That is correct. `async` in a server scenario is all about removing pressure on the thread pool.

> Is there any benefit to an async read of a resource (say a file or DB request) in an ASP.NET page vs. blocking on it?

Absolutely!

If you block on a file/service call/db request, then that thread is used for the duration of that operation. If you `await` a file/service call/db request, then that thread is immediately returned to the thread pool.

One (really cool!) result of this is that you can have a request in progress, and while it's (a)waiting some operation, there are *no* threads servicing that request! Zero-threaded concurrency, if you will.

When the operation completes, the method resumes after the `await` - on a (possibly different) thread from the thread pool.

In conclusion: `async` scales better than threads, so there is definitely a benefit on the server side.

More info: my own [intro to `async` post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [this *awesome* video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET).

Comment: Benefit caveat from this more recent [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30574578/1497596) of yours: "If you're talking about ASP.NET MVC with a single database backend, then you're (almost certainly) not going to get any scalability benefit from `async`. This is because IIS can handle far more concurrent requests than a single instance of SQL server (or other classic RDBMS). However, if your backend is more modern - a SQL server cluster, Azure SQL, NoSQL, etc - and your backend can scale, and your scalability bottleneck is IIS, *then* you can get a scalability benefit from `async`."