# How does EF use buffering when saving asynchronously?

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous

I just saw this post:
[Entity Framework - Saving results to the database asyncronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14466865/1987258)

which says:

> I'd like to save all the changes asynchronously because then I can call my web-service multiple times per second and just buffer any database changes to be saved by a quartz timer, which should lead to better performance.

It is not clear to how the buffering actually works and how the mentioned quartz timer works.

Comment: I think they are referring to the C# port of Quartz Scheduler.  http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/.  Essentially they want to "queue" the Entity Framework calls to an external job scheduler.

Comment: Maybe,but how does this "buffering" work? It does not become clear from msnd: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220070(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I didn't take from the question that there is any buffering involved, only that the person asking the question would like it to be so.

Comment: What I get from the quote is that "I'd like to save all the changes asynchronously" that is what he'd like to be it so. The actual reason is buffering which I do not know how this works.

Comment: Are you sure buffering isn't part of entity framework? https://github.com/mono/entityframework/search?p=3&q=buffering&utf8=%E2%9C%93