# When should I use Async Controllers in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, async-await

I have some concerns using async actions in ASP.NET MVC. When does it improve performance of my apps, and when does it *not*?

1. Is it good to use async action everywhere in ASP.NET MVC?
2. Regarding awaitable methods: shall I use async/await keywords when I want to query a database (via EF/NHibernate/other ORM)?
3. How many times can I use await keywords to query the database asynchronously in *one* single action method?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

**Asynchronous action** methods are useful when an action must perform several independent long running operations.

> A typical use for the AsyncController class is long-running Web
>   service calls.

Should my database calls be asynchronous ?

The IIS thread pool can often handle many more simultaneous blocking requests than a database server. If the database is the bottleneck, asynchronous calls will not speed up the database response. Without a throttling mechanism, efficiently dispatching more work to an overwhelmed database server by using asynchronous calls merely shifts more of the burden to the database. If your DB is the bottleneck, asynchronous calls won’t be the magic bullet.

You **should** have a look at [1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx) and [2](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1252/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc) references

Derived from @PanagiotisKanavos comments:

> Moreover, async doesn't mean parallel. Asynchronous execution frees a
>   valuable threadpool thread from blocking for an external resource, for
>   no complexity or performance cost. This means the same IIS machine can
>   handle more concurrent requests, not that it will run faster.
>
> You should also consider that blocking calls start with a
>   CPU-intensive spinwait. During stress times, blocking calls will
>   result in escalating delays and app pool recycling. Asynchronous calls
>   simply avoid this

Comment: Regarding async, IIS and the database, the blog post is extremely old and the conclusions drawn here are wrong. IIS has to server a *much* larger load than the database, threadpool threads are limited and a long request queue can lead to 500. Anything that frees up a thread while waiting for IO is beneficial. Even the links are *not* about what the OP asked. In fact the same authors have written that you *should* use asynchronous DB methods wherever you can

Comment: Moreover, async doesn't mean parallel. Asynchronous execution frees a valuable threadpool thread from blocking for an external resource, for no complexity or performance cost. This means *the same IIS machine* can handle *more* concurrent requests, not that it will run faster.

Comment: You should also consider that blocking calls start with a CPU-intensive spinwait. During stress times, blocking calls will result in escalating delays and app pool recycling. Asynchronous calls simply avoid this

Comment: Asynchronous usually means having a worker thread to do intensive work, freeing main thread from blocking task; but in case of ASP MVC I'm afraid it's not the same. 
@PanagiotisKanavos explained it well. And you can see the below answer for more detail.

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer and thus at the top for most people, it might be wise to remove second first paragraph regarding execution times and running in parallel, which has nothing to do with async. I realize there's a note at the end, but it *is* quite misleading.

Comment: Asynchronous execution frees a thread only in cases when it's truly async down to the very bottom of the implementation and uses some callback mechanism to signal readyness and to spin up a new thread to switch the context and process the result. So, I'm not sure in which cases this context switching / new thread creation is more efficient than just waiting for results in a single thread? Long running web service calls are a bad idea anyway, I prefer to offload it to a reliable background service and let the client check for results, which might come in a few minutes, hours or days.

Answer (score 264):

You may find my [MSDN article on the subject helpful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx); I took a lot of space in that article describing *when you should* use `async` on ASP.NET, not just *how* to use `async` on ASP.NET.

> I have some concerns using async actions in ASP.NET MVC. When it improves performance of my apps, and when - not.

First, understand that `async`/`await` is all about *freeing up threads*. On GUI applications, it's mainly about *freeing up the GUI thread* so the user experience is better. On server applications (including ASP.NET MVC), it's mainly about *freeing up the request thread* so the server can scale.

In particular, it *won't:*

- Make your individual requests complete faster. In fact, they will complete (just a teensy bit) slower.
- Return to the caller/browser when you hit an `await`. `await` only "yields" to the ASP.NET thread pool, not to the browser.

> First question is - is it good to use async action everywhere in ASP.NET MVC?

I'd say it's good to use it everywhere you're doing I/O. It may not necessarily be *beneficial*, though (see below).

However, it's **bad** to use it for CPU-bound methods. Sometimes devs think they can get the benefits of `async` by just calling `Task.Run` in their controllers, and this is a horrible idea. Because that code ends up freeing up the request thread by taking up another thread, so there's no benefit at all (and in fact, they're taking the penalty of extra thread switches)!

> Shall I use async/await keywords when I want to query database (via EF/NHibernate/other ORM)?

You could use whatever awaitable methods you have available. Right now most of the major players support `async`, but there are a few that don't. If your ORM doesn't support `async`, then don't try to wrap it in `Task.Run` or anything like that (see above).

Note that I said "you *could* use". If you're talking about ASP.NET MVC with a single database backend, then you're (almost certainly) not going to get any scalability benefit from `async`. This is because IIS can handle far more concurrent requests than a single instance of SQL server (or other classic RDBMS). However, if your backend is more modern - a SQL server cluster, Azure SQL, NoSQL, etc - and your backend can scale, and your scalability bottleneck is IIS, *then* you can get a scalability benefit from `async`.

> Third question - How many times I can use await keywords to query database asynchronously in ONE single action method?

As many as you like. However, note that many ORMs have a one-operation-per-connection rule. In particular, EF only allows a single operation per DbContext; this is true whether the operation is synchronous or asynchronous.

Also, keep in mind the scalability of your backend again. If you're hitting a single instance of SQL Server, and your IIS is already capable of keeping SQLServer at full capacity, then doubling or tripling the pressure on SQLServer is not going to help you at all.

Comment: Wouldn't the single database instance scenario benefit from freeing up a thread for, say, CPU-bound operations? No particular request would be faster, but the load on the server should be better optimized, enhancing the overall performance...

Comment: @seebiscuit: No. Because you don't end up "freeing up a thread" - you just end up jumping threads. You can't free up a thread with a CPU-bound operation, because it needs a thread to run on. You can free up the *request* thread - by using another thread - but all that does is cause an additional thread switch and possibly throw off the ASP.NET thread pool balancing heuristics.

Comment: Wow, very interesting. So I/O "free" threads are not available for CPU-bound ops?

Comment: @seebiscuit: When doing (proper asynchronous) I/O, no threads are used. I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) that goes into more detail.

Comment: Excellent answer. If the IIS thread pool > than the DB connection pool is it a deadlock waiting to happen? Assume requests all wait for the I/O result. Was reading this:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx

Comment: No, I don't see how that would cause a deadlock.

Comment: Allow multiple result sets is a setting that I suppose overcomes the limitation on EntityFramework default 1 op per context limit?

Comment: @Arwin: I don't know.

Comment: How many request can IIS and a single SQL Server instance handle? How can i find these numbers?

Comment: @MOD: It depends on configuration and hardware. The only way to find these numbers is to do a load test on your own server.

Comment: Sorry for this silly question, what do you mean with "CPU-bound methods"?

Comment: @Flezcano: Methods that execute fully on the CPU. I.e., they do not do I/O or blocking.

Comment: I am having 1 web api end point.Now if 1000 request hit this endpoints simultanoeusly does my code is responsible to handle this 1000 request like making this end point as fire and forget or this depends upon server and iis capability?

Comment: @Learning: Sorry, I don't understand the question, but it doesn't appear to be a clarification of this question/answer. Please ask a separate question on SO.

Comment: Sorry sir but SO wont accept this 2 liner question which i am trying to understand.when i was researching for this thing like if i have 1 web api end point which is called by 1000 users at same time then will this end point would be able to server each of this thousand request or i should make it async to handle 1000 of request?

Answer (score 27):

> is it good to use async action everywhere in ASP.NET MVC?

As usual in programming, it *depends*. There is always a trade-off when going down a certain path.

`async-await` shines in places where you know you'll receiving concurrent requests to your service and you want to be able to *scale out* well. How does `async-await` help with scaling out? In the fact that when you invoke a async IO call *synchronously*, such as a network call or hitting your database, the current thread which is responsible for the execution is blocked waiting for the request to finish. When you use `async-await`, you enable the framework to create a state machine for you which makes sure that after the IO call is complete, your method continues executing from where it left off.

A thing to note is that this state machine has a subtle overhead. Making a method asynchronous **does not make it execute faster**, and that is an important factor to understand and a misconception many people have.

Another thing to take under consideration when using `async-await` is the fact that it is *async all the way*, meaning that you'll see async penetrate your entire call stack, top to buttom. This means that if you want to expose synchronous API's, you'll often find yourself duplicating a certain amount of code, as [async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) and [sync](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) don't mix very well.

> Shall I use async/await keywords when I want to query database (via
>   EF/NHibernate/other ORM)?

If you choose to go down the path of using async IO calls, then yes, `async-await` will be a good choice, as more and more modern database providers expose async method implementing the TAP (Task Asynchronous Pattern).

> How many times I can use await keywords to query database
>   asynchronously in ONE single action method?

As many as you want, as long as you follow the rules stated by your database provider. There is no limit to the amount of async calls you can make. If you have queries which are independent of each other and can be made concurrently, you can spin a new task for each and use `await Task.WhenAll` to wait for both to complete.

Comment: Asynchronous db calls don't execute faster but allow the same IIS machine to server many more requests because threadpool threads aren't wasted. It also lowers CPU costs because blocking calls actually start with a CPU-intensive spinwait before actually blocking. In high load situations this can be the difference between the machine struggling or failing and recycling

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know, was that unclear from what I said?

Comment: Your answer doesn't mention the IIS specifics - the meltdown/recycle scenario is a primary reason to use async throughout. Someone who hasn't experienced it probably won't understand that `scale out well` may mean `your server won't die under load`. Or it may be a case of `once burned ...`

Answer (score 7):

`async` actions help best when the actions does some I\O operations to DB or some network bound calls where the thread that processes the request will be stalled before it gets answer from the DB or network bound call which you just invoked. It's best you use await with them and it will really improve the responsiveness of your application (because less ASP input\output threads will be stalled while waiting for the DB or any other operation like that). In all my applications whenever many calls to DB very necessary I've always wrapped them in awaiatable method and called that with `await` keyword.

Answer (score 7):

My 5 cents:

1. Use `async/await` if and only if you do an IO operation, like DB or external service webservice.
2. Always prefer async calls to DB.
3. Each time you query the DB.

P.S. There are exceptional cases for point 1, but you need to have a good understanding of async internals for this.

As an additional advantage, you can do few IO calls in parallel if needed:

```
Task task1 = FooAsync(); // launch it, but don't wait for result
Task task2 = BarAsync(); // launch bar; now both foo and bar are running
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2); // this is better in regard to exception handling
// use task1.Result, task2.Result
```

Answer (score 5):

As you know, MVC supports asynchronous controllers and you should take advantage of it. In case your Controller, performs a lengthy operation, (it might be a disk based I/o or a network call to another remote service), if the request is handled in synchronous manner, the IIS thread is busy the whole time. As a result, the thread is just waiting for the lengthy operation to complete. It can be better utilized by serving other requests while the operation requested in first is under progress. This will help in serving more concurrent requests.
Your webservice will be highly scalable and will not easily run into [C10k problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).
It is a good idea to use async/await for db queries. and yes you can use them as many number of times as you deem fit.

Take a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150516055057/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1252/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc) for excellent advise.

Answer (score 4):

My experience is that today a lot of developers use `async/await` as a default for controllers.

My suggestion would be, **use it only when you know it will help you**.

The reason is, as [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) and others already mentioned, it can introduce performance issues, rather than resolving them, and it will help you only in a specific scenario:

- High-traffic controllers
- Scalable backend

Answer (score 2):

> Is it good to use async action everywhere in ASP.NET MVC?

It's good to do so wherever you can use an async method especially when you have performance issues at the worker process level which happens for massive data and calculation operations. Otherwise, no need because unit testing will need casting.

> Regarding awaitable methods: shall I use async/await keywords when I
>   want to query a database (via EF/NHibernate/other ORM)?

Yes, it's better to use async for any DB operation as could as possible to avoid performance issues at the level of worker processes. 
Note that EF has created many async alternatives for most operations, such as:

```
.ToListAsync()
.FirstOrDefaultAsync()
.SaveChangesAsync()
.FindAsync()
```

> How many times can I use await keywords to query the database
>   asynchronously in one single action method?

The sky is the limit

Comment: Business logic for most web apps usually need highly sequential operations, so jumping between parallel processes in most cases is viable only at the very top level of the web request / worker process management, which doesn't deal with database requests directly anyway. I would really want to see some real world examples of a typical web application where it would be actually a good idea to process DB queries in async manner.