# How to implement multi threading in Orchard Modules?

Tags: c#, multithreading, module, orchardcms

This is a common question around multi threading in Orchard.

I have a module with a controller providing an action to execute a DB synchronization which takes a very long time. The action basically executes a for loop over several hundred items whereas each item could be processed / synchronized independently.

While researching how to improve performance i came across several possible solutions

- `async` / `await` keyword
- parallel for loop
- `Orchard.Environment.Work<>`
- `Orchard.Caching.IParallelCacheContext`
- `Orchard.Caching.ITask`
- `async` controller actions (also combined with the return value `Task<>`)

and many more.

What would be the best way to improve performance of the for loop without bypassing possible optimizations already implemented / provided in Orchard?

Comment: What is your bottle neck?

Comment: @Szymonides At the time i posted this question i had to optimize a synchronization task that was executed in a controller action of a module, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35230193/3936440. But then i thought it would be good idea to ask a common question as i didn't found anything on the net about threading in connection with Orchard.

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to spin new threads from an ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `async` / `await` / `Task<>` is nicely explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30574578/3936440
- parallel for loops may work but needs some kind of synchronization (e.g. use of `lock` keyword)
- `Orchard.Caching.*` is not for implementing multi threading stuff as the namespace already implieds
- `Work<>` is for lazy depency injection, see [What is the Work<> class for in Orchard CMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36307200/3936440)