# What is the Work<> class for in Orchard CMS?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

Plain and simple, what is the use case of the `Orchard.Environment.Work<>` class defined in `Orchard\Environment\WorkContextModule.cs`?

It can be found in several places like

```
private readonly Work<IContainerService> _containerService;

public Shapes(Work<IContainerService> containerService) {
  _containerService = containerService;
...
```

Is it for delayed resolution of `IContainerService`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Work` class is for lazy loading dependency injection. The dependency is not resolved when instantiating the class, but only when calling the `Value` property:

```
private readonly IMyService _myService;
private readonly IMyOtherService _myOtherService;
public MyClass(Work<IMyService> myService, IMyOtherService myOtherService) {
    // Just assign the Work class to the backing property
    // The dependency won't be resolved until '_myService.Value' is called
    _myService = myService;
    // The IMyOtherService is resolved and assigned to the _myOtherService property
    _myOtherService = myOtherService;
}
```

Now only when `_myService.Value` is called, the IMyService gets resolved by the Dependency resolver, which gives you the working of a lazy loading dependency injection.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was assuming.

Comment: It's a bit more than lazy loading. Lazy loading can be achieved by simply injecting `Lazy<T>`. `Work<T>` is similar, but it also ensures that the object is resolved from the current work scope, no matter what scope the requestor is in.

Comment: There is also another difference - each call to `Work<T>.Value` property will result in resolving an object from Autofac container, whereas calling `Lazy<T>.Value` multiple times will do it at most once.