# Is there any practical benefit of using await-async in action methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Is there any practical benefit of this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Movie.ToListAsync());
}
```

over this

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_context.Movie.ToList());
}
```

?

Will server waste its time if we use the latter code?

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30566848/728795)? It explains a lot

Comment: @Andrei The top answer is quite flawed - see the comments below. Most notably, async is *not* parallel.

Comment: @Rob ah, the old concurrent vs. async vs. parallel vs. threaded conversation. Can't have that one too many times.