# How do I allow missing dropdown list items to be added to a database without leaving the page in my MVC application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, razor, kendo-ui

It's something I've wondered about for some time now and it's easier in other frameworks I know.  I have made an MVC5 web application using razor views and KendoUI with a generic repository for database access.

On the create a form of one of the entities I have there are some KendoUI drop-down list widgets i.e.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
  .Name("Manager")
  .Filter("contains")
  .DataTextField("ManagerName")
  .DataValueField("ManagerName")
  .DataSource(source =>
  {
      source.Read(read =>
      {
          read.Action("GetData", "Data");
      }).ServerFiltering(false);
  }))
```

This, very simply, grabs its data from the `Datacontroller` `GetData` method as `JSON`.  There is no guarantee that all the `Managers` our users require will be in this list and so, to make life easier, I want to have a link that brings up a modal or something like that and allows them to add the missing Manager if they can't find it in the list but without leaving the `Create` view.

[image]

What is the best way to do this?  Should I be looking at `Asynchronous` controllers top achieve this? Are there any examples that people know of?

**Note:** My `Create` form is in an `Ajax` format.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a common action in a common controller. You're confusing async controllers, they are not for what you want. To see what MVC async controllers are about, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30567036/1267304).

You will need to just post common AJAX a request with the new item to be created and, after a successfull result, you add the newly created item in your dropdown list.

JS Code:

```
$("#ddl").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: {
        data: [{ Id: 1, Name: "John Doe"}, { Id: 1, Name: "Jane Doe"}]
    },
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataTextField: "Name"
});

$("#add").on("click", function() {
    wnd.center().open();
});

let wnd = $("#wnd-container").kendoWindow({
    title: "Add Item",
    modal: true,
    visible: false
}).data("kendoWindow");

$("#add-item").on("click", function() {
    // Pretend this is a legit post request where your new item's data 
    // will be sent to the MVC action to be added on database.
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js",
        success: function() {
            let ddl = $("#ddl").data("kendoDropDownList");

            ddl.dataSource.add({
                Id: 999,
                Name: $("#item-text").val()
            });

            wnd.close();

            ddl.select($(ddl.items()).last());
        }
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<input id="ddl">
<button type="button" id="add">Add Item</button>
<div id="wnd-container">
    Item Text: <input id="item-text"><br>
    <button id="add-item" type="button">Add Item</button>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/enEzefuS)