# Async controllers ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Does it make sense to make the controller asynchronous if I don't have asynchronous calls in my code. As far as I understand this is an antipattern, the thread has already been allocated from the pool, and since there is no asynchronous code, the asynchronous controller will only be a minus?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30566848/when-should-i-use-async-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Well it's not suggested https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios#important-info-and-advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.
More generically, there is no reason to make a method `async` if it never uses `await`.

This is not related to it running on a thread pool thread, just that `async` enables usage of `await` and requires that the method returns a `Task`/`Task<T>`/`void`.
But if you don't await anything, you just end up wrapping your result in a Task for no reason.